# Trying to make a graph with multiple lines using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and I have been trying to make a line graph with mupltiple lines. I have tried the 'plot' function but didn't get the desired result so I am now trying the ggplot. 
I keep running into error: 
`Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (100): x`
and there's obviously no graph output. 
Any help is much appreciated

I have rearranged my data, before it had 4 separate columns for different consumer types but now I have merged them and made a column that identifies each consumer.

This is the part of the code that generates the error

```
ggplot(data=consumers,aes(x=scenarios,y=unitary.bill)) +
 geom_line(aes(color=consumer.type,group=consumer.type))
```

my data looks like this:

```
    scenario unitary.bill consumer.type
1          1  0.076536835      net.cons
2          2  0.075835361      net.cons
3          3  0.076696548      net.cons
4          4  0.076431602      net.cons
5          5  0.076816135      net.cons
.........
27         2  0.076794287    smart.cons
28         3  0.075555555    smart.cons
29         4  0.077126955    smart.cons
30         5  0.077925161    smart.cons
.......
100       25  0.049247761    smart.pros
```

I expect the a line graph to have four different colors (each representing my consumer type) and the scenarios at the x-axis.

Comment: try `ggplot(data=consumers,aes(x = scenarios,y = unitary.bill, colour= consumer.type)) + geom_line()` Passing the group in within `aes() ` aka aesthetics is what is causing the error

Comment: The only error I get is from the fact that your column is called scenario, not scenarios. Maybe you have a variable scenarios elsewhere?

Comment: you are right Camille, I changed that and used the code from Informer and voila, I have my graph. I will paste it in the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help from Camille and Infominer. My code now looks like this (I added some more details)

```
ggplot(data=consumers,aes(x = scenarios,y = unitary.bill, colour= SMCs)) +
 geom_line(size=1) + scale_colour_manual(values=c("indianred1", "yellowgreen","lightpink","springgreen4"))+
 ggtitle("           Unitary bill for each SMC type at the end of the scenario runs")+
 scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25))
```

and the graph looks as I wanted it to. However, if I could put some more distance between the title and the graph that will make it prettier. 
[you can view the graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hGtU.jpg)